# PHP get database object's database name

Tags: php, mysqli

The ancient `mysql` extension has a `mysql_db_name` function to retrieve the name of the database for the specified database resource however looking through php.net I'm not finding an equivalent. I work with two databases sometimes and I need the error reports to return the correct *database name* that the connection is using when I encounter an error.

Using the modern `mysqli` extension how do I determine later on (e.g. error handling) what the name of the database the database connection object is currently connected to?

The context is a custom database error handling function and the database connection is simply referenced as `$db`.

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host1,$user1,$pass1,'db1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DATABASE()` MySQL function returns the current database. So you can get it with a query:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT DATABASE() AS db");
$row = $results->fetch_assoc();
$curdb = $row['db'];
```

Comment: I forgot about MariaDB's built in query functions, thank you. Will accept when the timer allows me.